# My blazor Parameters are just returning the variable name as a string instead of the variables text

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, webassembly

Im trying to pass a series of info through blazor [parameter].
Each time when trying to pass a string which updates depending on a buttons state, instead of changing the text. The text just becomes the variable name.

Im not passing the strings as a parameter correctly.

```
// Main
 <section class="p-4">
     @if (showImagePreviewContainer)
     {
         <ImagePreviewContainer ClosePreviewContainer="ClosePreviewContainer"
                                currentImageUrl="currentImageUrl" />
     }

     <div class="text-center">
         <h3 class="text-3xl font-bold mb-2">Library</h3>
         <h4 class="text-xl">Access your saved and purchased designs</h4>
     </div>#

     <section class="my-2 mx-auto">
         <LibraryItemsContainer freeImagesOpen="freeImagesOpen"
                                buttonText="buttonText"
                                ToggleFreeImagesContainer="ToggleFreeImagesContainer"
                                OpenPreviewContainer="OpenPreviewContainer"
                                currentImageUrl="currentImageUrl" />
     </section>
 </section>

    // C#

    // Images
    public bool showImagePreviewContainer { get; set; } = false;
    public string currentImageUrl { get; set; } = "";

    public void OpenPreviewContainer()
    {
        showImagePreviewContainer = true;
    }    

    public void ClosePreviewContainer()
    {
        showImagePreviewContainer = false;
    }


// Container

<section>
    <div>
        <div class="grid justify-center my-4">
            <button class="outline outline-1 outline-black rounded hover:bg-main-colour cursor-pointer py-2 px-4 mt-4" @onclick="toggleFreeImages">@buttonText</button>
        </div>
        <div class="@(freeImagesOpen ? "grid" : "hidden")">
            <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-4 mx-auto mt-4">
                @foreach (var image in ImagesContainer.ImageList)
                {
                    <div class="p-2 outline outline-1 outline-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer grid items-center justify-center w-[75px] h-[75px]" title="@image.Name">
                        <img class="" src="@image.FilePath" alt="@image.Name" @onclick="@(e => PreviewImage(@image.FilePath))"/>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

@code {
    public FreeImages ImagesContainer = new FreeImages();

    [Parameter]
    public bool freeImagesOpen { get; set; }    

    [Parameter]
    public string? currentImageUrl { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? buttonText { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback ToggleFreeImagesContainer { get; set; }

    public async Task toggleFreeImages()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"buttons {buttonText}");
        await ToggleFreeImagesContainer.InvokeAsync();
    }    

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OpenPreviewContainer { get; set; }

    public async Task PreviewImage(string filePath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"IMAGE SSSS");
        currentImageUrl = filePath;
        await OpenPreviewContainer.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

The booleans pass ok.
But my button just displays 'buttonText'
and my currentImageUrl just says 'currentImageUrl' im the image tag

I have tried various ways of passing the data like you would in JS but seems i cant find the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When having a string as parameter you'll need to provide an @ in front of your variable. Otherwise it creates a new string with the name you have entered.
Simple change.

From

```
<ImagePreviewContainer ClosePreviewContainer="ClosePreviewContainer"
                                currentImageUrl="currentImageUrl" />
```

To

```
<ImagePreviewContainer ClosePreviewContainer="ClosePreviewContainer"
                                currentImageUrl="@currentImageUrl" />
```